# Composition of Maps

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, syntax

I want to create a composition of several lists. For example:

```
list1 = {1, 2};
list2 = {3, 4};
list3 = {5, 6};
Table[ list1[[i]] list2[[j]] list3[[k]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}, {k, 1, 2}]
{{{15, 18}, {20, 24}}, {{30, 36}, {40, 48}}}
```

However, I want to make it using `Map` function. I understand how to create a product of two lists:

```
Map[list1 # &, list2]
{{3, 6}, {4, 8}}
```

But I need to make something like

```
Map[Map[(list1*#1*#2) &, list2] &, list3]
```

Which doesn't work properly.

Comment: Outer[Times, Outer[Times, l1, l2], l3]

Comment: What you're doing here is equivalent to `Outer[Times, list1, list2, list3]`. `Map` is probably not the right thing to use here.

Comment: Btw., `TensorProduct[list1, list2, list3]` might be a bit more efficient than `Outer`. (But this may depend on the version number...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is:

```
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        for k in list3:
            Times[i,j,k]
```

Which means, you need to construct a `Cartesian product`

F1 ,search it:

[image]

So we need `Outer`

According to F1

```
Outer[Times, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {a, b, c}]
```

this gives the Outer product of vector

Which is what you need.

```
Outer[Times, list1, list2, list3]
```

Comment: great,thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well, [`TensorProduct`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct.html) finishes the one-step job without the help of any other functions:

```
TensorProduct[list1, list2, list3]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Table` is also work.

```
list1 = {1, 2};
list2 = {3, 4};
list3 = {5, 6};
Table[i*j*k, {i, list1}, {j, list2}, {k, list3}]
```

and for some `f`

```
list1 = {1, 2};
list2 = {3, 4};
list3 = {5, 6};
Table[f[i,j,k],{i,list1},{j,list2},{k,list3}]
```

the result is the same as

```
list1 = {1, 2};
list2 = {3, 4};
list3 = {5, 6};
Outer[f,list1,list2,list3]
```